# How can I proxy HTTPS requests using react-native

Tags: proxy, react-native, httpsurlconnection

I have an HTTPS endpoint I want to access using a proxy. I tried several modules such as axios, requests and others. But it seems the proxy configs I put in aren't being used.

How can I access an endpoints through a proxy using react-native?

Thanks

Comment: did you try this package http-proxy-middleware

Comment: I think that package works only on backend servers. Not on react-native